# Нормально ли, что stunnel запускается со статусом Ss?

Tags: c++, ssh-tunnel, tunnel

Пытаюсь запустить туннель от КриптоПро в системе Sailfish OS.
При запуске командой `./stunnel_thread /pathtofolder/stunnel.conf` туннель запускается в статусе Ss

```
1269 ?        Ss     0:00 ./stunnel_thread /pathtofolder/stunnel.conf
1298 pts/12   S+     0:00 grep stunnel
```

Не понимаю, работает он или нет. Если делать пустой post запрос через Qt, то прилетает ошибка.

Запрос

```
void WebViewModel::sendPOST(QString url)
{
    QNetworkCookieJar *cookieJar = new QNetworkCookieJar(manager_);
    manager_->setCookieJar(cookieJar);

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QStringLiteral("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    QByteArray postData;
    postData.append("");

    connect(manager_, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(replyFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply *)));

    manager_->post(request, postData);
}

void WebViewModel::replyFinishedSlot(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if(reply->error())
    {
        qDebug() << "Ошибка: ";
        qDebug() << reply->errorString();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << reply->readAll();
    }
    reply->deleteLater();
}
```

Ошибка

```
WebViewModel::replyFinishedSlot:46 - "Error transferring http:... - server replied: Bad Request"
```

Лог туннеля:

```
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG5[1268:4105371664]: stunnel 4.18 on armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG5[1268:4105371664]: Threading:PTHREAD Sockets:POLL,IPv6
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG6[1268:4105371664]: file ulimit = 1024 (can be changed with 'ulimit -n')
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG6[1268:4105371664]: poll() used - no FD_SETSIZE limit for file descriptors
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG5[1268:4105371664]: 0 clients allowed
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG7[1268:4105371664]: FD 4 in non-blocking mode
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG7[1268:4105371664]: FD 5 in non-blocking mode
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG7[1268:4105371664]: FD 6 in non-blocking mode
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG7[1268:4105371664]: SO_REUSEADDR option set on accept socket
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG7[1268:4105371664]: https bound to 127.0.0.1:8080
2021.09.28 13:27:22 LOG7[1269:4105371664]: Created pid file /pathtofolder/stunnel.pid
```

Сам конфиг

```
pid = /pathtofolder/stunnel.pid
output = /pathtofolder/stunnel.log
socket = l:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = r:TCP_NODELAY=1
socket = a:SO_REUSEADDR=1
debug = 7
client = yes
delay = yes
[https]
accept = 127.0.0.1:8080
connect = address:443
cert = /pathtofolder/cerfile.cer
verify = 0
```

Comment: меня смущает фраза "0 clients allowed"

Comment: @KoVadim а что это означает для работы туннеля и как это поправить?

Comment: если дословно перевести, то это значит, что ни один клиент не подключится, потому что только 0 разрешено. Хотя иногда 0 значит "неограничено". Я работал с stunnel раньше, но такого никогда не видел.

Comment: @KoVadim а вообще, нормально ли, что он запускается со статусом Ss?

Comment: большая буква S, если я правильно помню, значит, что процесс находится в прерываемом сне - то есть, он чего то ждет. Например, он висит в read или accept ждет подключения. Так как это сервер - это ожидаемое его состояние.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо за разъяснение.